# Can someone translate this shirt for me?

Tags: перевод, транслитерация

I think it says good! all is well when the wind blows, but can someone write this in print! (like: хорошо! всё)  thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Alright! Everything's gonna be alright! (Bob Marley)

Comment: I don't think a downvote here is appropriate.  Bob Marley's quote is actually a perfect translation.

Answer (score 7):

The printed phrase is "Хорошо! Всё будет хорошо!". It means "Okay! It will be okay!". Probably, this phrase is a quotation from lyrics of the famous Ukrainian songer Andrey Danilko. He has an eponymous song.

Comment: what does that translate to?

Comment: @GamerGuy, could you be more specific? I wrote the meaning of the printed text. What's unclear to you?

Comment: nevermind. I was confused

Comment: I kind of wonder, who was the poet that wrote this song lyrics. Danilko does not appear as bard to me.

Answer (score 2):

While there are [several](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE) [ways](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&oq=%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&gs_l=psy-ab.3.2.0i71k1l4.0.0.0.323954.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.6BcZ_kz5fN8) to use the word (e.g. good, well, OK). Once you separate each word it'd read:

```
"Хорошо! Всё будет хорошо!"
```

reads:

```
"Good! Everything will be good!"
```

However a more colloquial English equivalent example would be:

```
Well! All is well!
```

Also, there's a popular Russian song with that title by [ВЕРКА СЕРДЮЧКА - ВСЕ БУДЕТ ХОРОШО](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Am5AEPHd6k).

Comment: I wonder if this song would be correctly said as Russian or Russian-language Ukrainian one. It is not folklore, it have a known writer and a known performer.

Comment: Possibly related, but there is no "будет", just "всё хорошо": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-uLtUqSBck